# Angle created by tilting a plane.

Tags: plane-geometry, angle

I have a math problem involving tilting planes and the getting the angle of the normal from the starting point normal to the new normal after the plane is tilted.

I have a plane $x-y$ with a normal $z$. The plane tilts, lets say $+4$ degrees along the $x$, and $+18$ degrees along the $y$.

How do I solve for the angle between the original normal to the plane and the new normal to the new plane as created by the $x$ and $y$ angular changes?

Also how do I calculate the direction angle (as in a compass) that the new normal $z$ projects onto the original plane? This doesn't seem like it should be hard but it has me puzzled.

Thanks

Comment: Originally $z$ is at right angle both to $x$ and $y$. Then during the rotation $x$ goes to $x'$, $y$ to $y'$ and $z$ to $z'$. Now, obviously, if the rotation is $4^{\circ}$ along $x$, then the angle between $z'$ and $x$ is not changed, but the angle between $z'$ and $y$ is now $4^{\circ}$ less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the well-known Rodriguez rotation formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula), which states

$
\textbf{v}' = \textbf{v}\cos\theta + (\textbf{r}\times\textbf{v})\sin\theta + \textbf{r}(\textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{r})(1-\cos\theta)
$

where $\textbf{v}$ is the original vector, $\textbf{r}$ is the vector about which the rotation on angle $\theta$ is performed, and $\textbf{v}'$ is the vector after rotation.

Now, by applying this formula twice (first, for example, for the rotation on angle $\alpha$ about $x-$axis and then on angle $\beta$ around $y-$axis), we get

$\textbf{k}'' = \textbf{i}\cos\alpha\sin\beta -\textbf{j}\sin\alpha + \textbf{k}\cos\alpha\cos\beta$.

Now, to find the angle between $\textbf{k}$ and $\textbf{k}''$, you can take the dot-product of them

$\cos \angle(\textbf{k},\textbf{k}'') = \textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{k}'' = \cos\alpha\cos\beta$.

The compass direction is given by the vector $\textbf{k}''_{||} = \textbf{i}\cos\alpha\sin\beta -\textbf{j}\sin\alpha$.

Now, let consider specific example of $\alpha = 4^\circ$ and $\beta = 18^\circ$. In this case, $\cos \alpha = 0.9976$, $\sin\alpha = 0.07$, $\cos\beta = 0.951$, and $\sin\beta = 0.309$. As a result, combining all these numbers together, we get

$\angle(\textbf{k},\textbf{k}'') = 18.42^\circ$,

and the compass direction with respect to the the original $x-$axis is $-\tan^{-1}(\tan\alpha\sin\beta) = 1.24^\circ$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pavel - it has been a while since I took college math, so would you be so kind as to work an example with x=4° and y=12°? That would be a great help.

Comment: @tmig: check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, now it is all clear!

Comment: figured it out - thanks again.